# Getting Local Printer Status in PHP

Tags: php, printing

I am attempting to query a local printer strictly using PHP. The goal is to have PHP notify the user when the printer is out of paper. I have looked at a few libraries but they all seem to only be able to access a network printer. I have yet to find a utility that will emulate a virtual network printer so that I can utilize the current libraries available.

Is there currently a solution to query local printers in PHP, or emulate a network printer so that I can utilize the current features in PHP?

For clarification, this is on a windows machine. Ultimately if I can find a utility to simulate a network printer on a localhost, then my problem would be solved.

Comment: No, there is no way to do this in PHP.

Comment: Is this meant to be run on a web server or from console? Also, is this on windows or a *nix system?

Comment: Use the shell to get that kind of information.

Comment: print.exe and printui.exe sound interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhP is not really suited for remote hardware polling on its own. 
Are you on windows or *nix/mac?

you could try executing a shell script to check and return printer status (there are quite a few around and are relatively trivial to adapt to network printers if they are already configured on system) on *nix

and installing some of the remote server admin tools with network printer management windows components will allow you to make sys calls which 'might' do what you want. plus theres always 'printui.exe' and 'print.exe' i guess.

Comment: I am on a windows machine. I'm taking a look into 'printui.exe' and 'print.exe'. Thanks!

Comment: Your answer was perfect! 'PrintUI.exe' not only returns the status of the printer, but will give an error to the user if any problems arise.